# TailWind not applying in Phoenix/Elixir project

Tags: elixir, tailwind-css, phoenix-framework

I am trying to migrate from Bootstrap to TailWind and it is not applying the styles from my html in the browser. I followed the documentation for Phoenix specifically, but for some reason it's not watching/building with TailWind.

mix.exs:

```
 defp aliases do
    [
      "assets.deploy": ["tailwind default --minify", "esbuild default --minify", "phx.digest"]
    ]
  end
```

tailwind.config.js:

```
let plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
  important: true,
  content: [
    './js/**/*.{js,vue}',
    '../lib/*_web.ex',
    '../lib/*_web/**/*.*ex',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    plugin(({addVariant}) => addVariant('phx-no-feedback', ['&.phx-no-feedback', '.phx-no-feedback &'])),
    plugin(({addVariant}) => addVariant('phx-click-loading', ['&.phx-click-loading', '.phx-click-loading &'])),
    plugin(({addVariant}) => addVariant('phx-submit-loading', ['&.phx-submit-loading', '.phx-submit-loading &'])),
    plugin(({addVariant}) => addVariant('phx-change-loading', ['&.phx-change-loading', '.phx-change-loading &']))
  ]
}
```

app.css:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

config.exs:

```
config :tailwind, version: "3.2.4", default: [
  args: ~w(
    --config=tailwind.config.js
    --input=css/app.css
    --output=../priv/static/assets/app.css
  ),
  cd: Path.expand("../assets", __DIR__)
]
```

dev.exs:

```
watchers: [
  tailwind: {Tailwind, :install_and_run, [:default, ~w(--watch)]}
]
```